# jQuery closest() or prevAll() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user hovers over the link with the class `"thumb"`  the closest link with the class `"title"` should have the class `"media-link-hover"` applied to it. How can this be done?

I tried `closest()` and also this but nothing seems to be working:

```
$('a.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this)
        .prevAll('.block')
        .find('a.title')
        .addClass('media-link-hover');
}, function() {
    $(this)
        .prevAll('.block')
        .find('a.title')
        .removeClass('media-link-hover');
});
```

HTML:

```
<article class="block">
    <div class="inner-left">
        <a class="thumb" title="" href="">
            <img width="198" height="111" alt="" src="" />
            <span class="media-overlay">video</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-right">
        <a class="title" title="" href="">Hello</a>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Hi there</p>
            <a class="teaser" href="">Hola</a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-stats">
            <span class="finder">Found by <strong>Me</strong> 1 month ago</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Add something in your `href` to your `<a class="thumb">`

Comment: You're saying `.closest('.block').find('a.title')` didn't work? It should. [Here's a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rPJYm/)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, your issue is elsewhere, and you'll need to provide more code.

Comment: Why are you using [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)? Please read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `parents()` and also you can reduce the code by using `toggleClass()`.
**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Ce8fu/

```
$('a.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this)
        .parents('.block')
        .find('a.title')
        .toggleClass('media-link-hover');
});
```

Comment: Way `parents` and not `closest`? do you really need traverse the DOM up to the `<body>`?

Comment: Yeah, `closest()` should work too...Don't know why it isn't working for him.

Comment: Turns out `parents()` is way faster, at least on Chrome and FF. http://jsperf.com/parents-vs-closest-jquery

Comment: @elclanrs: In your jsPerf, `this` wasn't pointing to anything meaningful. http://jsperf.com/parents-vs-closest-jquery/2

Answer (score 4):

Works with `closest('.block')`

http://jsfiddle.net/yBwSN/

Comment: How is your answer different from the other user whom you criticized for suggesting `.closest('.block')`?

Comment: *"Thats what he's doing. did you read his code?" – AlienWebguy 14 mins ago*

Comment: If you read the other user's answer he said closest and prevAll only go up the tree, not back down each branch, and then suggested to add `find()`.

Comment: His solution was: `$(this).closest(".block").find("a.title").addClass("media-link-hover");`, about which you wrote: *"Thats what he's doing. did you read his code?"*... Then after he deleted, you proceeded to post the same solution. You're not actually defending that, are you?

Comment: You're missing the point. He suggested find() as an additional requirement because closest and prevAll only traverse upward. I said the OP was already doing that in his example. Are you still confused?

Comment: No, I'm not at all confused. His was a quick and sloppy inclusion of `.prevAll()` when describing `.closest()`, and your criticism of his answer had nothing to do with that. Your criticism was that the solution he provided had already been tried, and as a result he deleted, and then you posted the same solution. I understand that you're trying your hardest to hang your justification on the `.prevAll()` description, but I'm afraid it doesn't alter how lame it is to criticize someone's solution, then post that same solution.

Comment: I'm sorry you're struggling to understand what happened. It had nothing to do with `prevAll()` it had to do with him suggesting to use `find()` to traverse back down, when the OP was already doing it. I didn't tell him to or suggest for him to delete his answer. I'm glad you're looking out for him though, StackOverflow needs more guardians like you.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. This started off lame, but now it's just getting sad. Obviously you hoped no one would call you out on it. Fine, I'll let you pretend you didn't do what you did. Yay! Great answer! And you get points! +1 Yay! More points! That other guy should have read the code, just like you told him.

Comment: Pretty apparent it's not making sense to you. Thanks for the upvote, guardian.

Comment: You're very welcome. Great answer though. Just like the other guy *(though I liked his a little better, as it included full solution in the answer, instead of just in the fiddle)*. Not sure why you didn't upvote him.